# How to make a method work in a period of time in C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been struggling for a while on this code of mine. 
I have a method for my player that when it collects a certain amount of collectables it goes faster. But I want my player to go faster for a certain amount of time (like for example 3 seconds). And the counter (for the collectables) has to go back to zero, so when the player collects again a certain amount of collectables it goes again faster, etc.

I have a class for all my PowerUp and a diffrent class: Speder that inherit from PowerUp.
The speed variable that has go up when it collects a certain amount of collectables is in my players script: Player0.

PowerUp

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
  public static int counter = 0;

  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
  {
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
      Speder.BoostThaSpeed();
      Destroy(this.gameObject);
      counter++;

      if (counter == 3)
      {
        counter = 0;
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Speder

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Speder : PowerUp
{
  public static void BoostThaSpeed()
  {
    if (counter == 2)
    {
      Player0.speed = Player0.speed * 2;
    }

    else if (counter < 2)
    {
      Player0.speed = Player0.speed = 3.5f;
    }
  }
  void OnGUI()
  {
    GUI.Box(new Rect(750, 0, 130, 20), "Counter:" + counter);
  }
}
```

Player0

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player0 : MonoBehaviour
{

  // SPEEDVARIABLES
  public static float speed = 3.5f;

void Update()
  {
 // MOVING CODE

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
      rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);   // - speedForce (om naar links te gaan)
      transform.localScale = new Vector3(-0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);   
    }

    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
      rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);   // + speedforce (om naar rechts te gaan)
      transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
    }

    else
    {
     rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Time.deltaTime in your update methods to reduce a variable

add a SpeedboostTimeRemaining property to Speder and set it to whatever time, say 10 in the BoostThaSpeed method

then add an update method to Speder and put

```
if(SpeedboostTimeRemaining > 0)
{
    SpeedboostTimeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime
    if(SpeedboostTimeRemaining < 0)
    {
        SpeedboostTimeRemaining = 0;
        Player0.speed = 3.5f;
    }
}
```

Comment: although, I think you need to refactor to reduce your use of global objects